# Dynamicly generated layouts takes much time, how to make it more effective, android

Tags: android, layout

Hi i am creating dynamicly linear layouts and textviews inside and seting onclick events on each textview, but because the data from the sqlite query i make is big it takes a lot of time the binding to finish ( about 5-6sec) can anyone refer me to a much more effective way to do what i want to achive? I cannot use ListView because it is continuing text that should not be separeted, i tried to call

i tried to do something like this

```
  onCreate(...){...
  Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    filldata(BID,CID);// add 30 views
    }
};
LinearEn.post(r);// this is the main linearlayout that i add views and layers to it

 }

 public void filldata(idB, idC){
   ....

   for(i=0;i<VerseArr.length;i++){ // this is the for loop that holds select query sqlite

            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            LinearLayout Infant1Layout = new LinearLayout(Reads.this);
            LinearLayout Infant2Layout = new LinearLayout(Reads.this);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            linearParams2.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
            Infant2Layout.setLayoutParams(linearParams2);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            linearParams1.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
            linearParams1.setMargins(0,0,15,0);
            Infant1Layout.setLayoutParams(linearParams1);
            Infant1Layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            TextView BookTxt=new TextView(Reads.this);
            TextView BookVerseNum=new TextView(Reads.this);

            BookTxt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>"+VerseArr[i]+"<font>"));
            BookTxt.setTypeface(tf);
            BookTxt.setFadingEdgeLength(10);
            BookTxt.setTextSize(17.2f);
            int currentAPIVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

            if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                BookTxt.setTextIsSelectable(true);
            }

            BookTxt.setPadding(0, dpToPx(3), dpToPx(5), 0);

            BookVerseNum.setText(Html.fromHtml("<small><font color='#F9F9F9'>"+(i+1)+"<font></small>"));
            BookVerseNum.setTypeface(tf);
            BookVerseNum.setFadingEdgeLength(10);
            BookVerseNum.setTextSize(20.2f);
            BookVerseNum.setPadding(dpToPx(valuePad), dpToPx(3), dpToPx(5), dpToPx(3));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0,0, 0, 4);
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
            Infant1Layout.addView(BookVerseNum);

            View v = new View(this);
            v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    1,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B3B3B3"));
            v.setPadding(dpToPx(15), 0, dpToPx(15), dpToPx(3));

            Infant1Layout.addView(v);
            Infant2Layout.addView(BookTxt);
            linearLayout.addView(Infant1Layout);
            linearLayout.addView(Infant2Layout);
            LinearEn.addView(linearLayout);
        }   


  }
```

Comment: I think if you create XML layout(s) and process them in code, it might be helpful.

Comment: Why don't you create your view using an XML layout file? It's hard to tell what sort of view you're trying to create but it pretty much looks like a list or similar.

Comment: just use a ListView,  i don't  see any reason  why you cannot do that

Comment: because i have sometimes 30 layouts to create, and somethimes 10

Comment: @Deron : A `ListView` will handle that automatically. All you do is create a list item layout XML then use it with some sort of `Adapter` with a `ListView`. Android is good at this sort of thing and extremely fast.

Comment: I think i tried with list view but this is a book that has it chapters and every chapter will represent another row in the list view i didnt manage to make it to look readable instead it looks like to choose which row u want

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats because

```
for(i=0;i<VerseArr.length;i++)
```

here based the `VerseArr.length` say 20 those many views will be created so it takes time, some times if there are more say like 300 or so it might give us OOM as well.

But still, i have tried dynamically creating views for 4 to 5 or so but it will not take so much time, what i can suggest you is keep the Data ready that need to be added and try to `reuse the views instead of creating it every time`